# How to differentiate CT images from two different manufacturers using DCMTK commands?

Tags: dicom, dcmtk

I am trying to pull images from a server. I am interested in pulling CT images for a specific patient. I am executing the following DCMTK commands from the command prompt (windows):

1) I get the Study Instance UID of my Patient ID (0020,000D)

```
findscu -v -aet DCMTK -aec VMSDBD 10.196.XX.XXX 51XXX -S -k PatientID=303XXXXX -k QueryRetrieveLevel=STUDY -k 0020,000D
```

**OUTPUT:**

> ....
>
> I: (0010,0020) LO [303XXXXX]                               #   8, 1 PatientID
>
> I: (0020,000d) UI [1.2.840.113619.2.278.3.346865037.482.15052672XX.XXX ] #  52, 1 StudyInstanceUID
>
> ....

2) I get the Series Instance UIDs of the CT modalities present in the study (0020,000E):

```
findscu -aet DCMTK -aec VMSDBD 10.196.XX.XXX 51XXX -S -k PatientID=3038XXXX -k QueryRetrieveLevel=SERIES -k "0020,000D=1.2.840.113619.2.278.3.346865037.482.1505267XXXX.XXX" -k "0008,0060=CT" -k 0020,000E
```

**OUTPUT:**

> ...
>
> Serie 1: Manufacturer 1
>
> I: (0008,0060) CS [CT]                                     #   2, 1 Modality
>
> I: (0010,0020) LO [3038XXXX]                               #   8, 1 PatientID
>
> I: (0020,000d) UI [1.2.840.113619.2.278.3.346865037.388.15390421XX.XXX ] #  52, 1 StudyInstanceUID
>
> I: (0020,000e) UI [1.2.246.352.62.2.4715824891563742196.178434434465388XXXX ] #  56, 1 SeriesInstanceUID
>
> I: (0020,0011) IS [2 ]                                     #   2, 1 SeriesNumber
>
> ...
>
> Serie 2 : Manufacturer 2
>
> I: (0008,0060) CS [CT]                                     #   2, 1 Modality
>
> I: (0010,0020) LO [3038XXXX]                               #   8, 1 PatientID
>
> I: (0020,000d) UI [1.2.840.113619.2.278.3.346865037.388.15390421XX.XXX ] #  52, 1 StudyInstanceUID
>
> I: (0020,000e) UI [1.2.840.113619.2.278.3.346865037.388.15390421XX.XXX ] #  56, 1 SeriesInstanceUID
>
> I: (0020,0011) IS [3 ]                                     #   2, 1 SeriesNumber
>
> ...

3) I can now just use the Series Instance UIDs to pull the CT images from the server:

```
movescu –aet DCMTK –aec VMSDBD -aem VMSFSD-OUT –S -k 0008,0052=SERIES -k 0020,000E=1.2.840.113619.2.278.3.346865037.388.15390421XX.XXX 10.196.XX.XXX 51XXX
```

**OUTPUT**

> ...
>
> I: (0020,000e) UI [1.2.840.113619.2.278.3.346865037.388.15390421XX.XXX] #  54, 1 SeriesInstanceUID
>
> I: Received Move Response 1 (Pending)
>
> ...

The problem is that the patients have two types of CT series: "ConeBeam CT" and "CT:

But the Modality tag (0008,0060) for both types of CT series is "CT". I just want to pull the "ConeBeam" CT series. With the previous commands I am pulling everything (both of them). i.e. I cannot distinguish "ConeBeam CT" from "CT".

So, Is there any way to differentiate the "ConeBeam CT" series from the "CT" series using the DCMTK commands?

Following is the dump for "ConeBeam CT" header:

```
(0002,0000) Group Length                                        VR: UL  Length: 4    Value: 188 
(0002,0001) File Meta Information Version                       VR: OB  Length: 2    Value: 0
(0002,0002) Media Storage SOP Class UID                         VR: UI  Length: 26   Value: 
(0002,0003) Media Storage SOP Instance UID                      VR: UI  Length: 58   Value: 
(0002,0010) Transfer Syntax UID                                 VR: UI  Length: 18   Value: 
(0002,0012) Implementation Class UID                            VR: UI  Length: 24   Value: 
(0002,0013) Implementation Version Name                         VR: SH  Length: 8    Value: DCIE 2.2
(0008,0005) Specific Character Set                              VR: CS  Length: 10   Value: ISO_IR 192
(0008,0008) Image Type                                          VR: CS  Length: 22   Value: ORIGINAL\PRIMARY\AXIAL
(0008,0012) Instance Creation Date                              VR: DA  Length: 8    Value: 20181115
(0008,0013) Instance Creation Time                              VR: TM  Length: 6    Value: 150640
(0008,0016) SOP Class UID                                       VR: UI  Length: 26   Value: 
(0008,0018) SOP Instance UID                                    VR: UI  Length: 58   Value: 1.2.246.352.62.1.4658378903620750311.171271252736726XXXXX
(0008,0020) Study Date                                          VR: DA  Length: 8    Value: 20181009
(0008,0021) Series Date                                         VR: DA  Length: 8    Value: 20181101
(0008,0022) Acquisition Date                                    VR: DA  Length: 8    Value: 20181101
(0008,0023) Image Date                                          VR: DA  Length: 8    Value: 20181101
(0008,0030) Study Time                                          VR: TM  Length: 6    Value: 111141
(0008,0031) Series Time                                         VR: TM  Length: 10   Value: 114125.627
(0008,0032) Acquisition Time                                    VR: TM  Length: 10   Value: 114048.727
(0008,0033) Image Time                                          VR: TM  Length: 10   Value: 114048.727
(0008,0050) Accession Number                                    VR: SH  Length: 0    
(0008,0060) Modality                                            VR: CS  Length: 2    Value: CT
(0008,0070) Manufacturer                                        VR: LO  Length: 22   Value: Varian Medical Systems
(0008,0090) Referring Physician's Name                          VR: PN  Length: 8    Value:  
(0008,1010) Station Name                                        VR: SH  Length: 10   Value:  
(0008,1030) Study Description                                   VR: LO  Length: 2    Value: HN
(0008,1048) Physician(s) of Record                              VR: PN  Length: 14   Value:  
(0008,1070) Operators' Name                                     VR: PN  Length: 14   Value: DICOM Service 
(0008,1090) Manufacturer's Model Name                           VR: LO  Length: 10   Value: RDS - PVA 
(0008,114A) Referenced Instance Sequence                        VR: SQ  Length: 222  
    (FFFE,E000) 
        (0008,1150) Referenced SOP Class UID                            VR: UI  Length: 20   Value: 
        (0008,1155) Referenced SOP Instance UID                         VR: UI  Length: 52   Value: 
        (0040,A170) Purpose of Reference Code Sequence                  VR: SQ  Length: 118  
            (FFFE,E000) 
                (0008,0100) Code Value                                          VR: SH  Length: 4    Value: 1000
                (0008,0102) Coding Scheme Designator                            VR: SH  Length: 16   Value: 99VMS_PURPREFOBJ
                (0008,0103) Coding Scheme Version                               VR: SH  Length: 4    Value: 1.0 
                (0008,0104) Code Meaning                                        VR: LO  Length: 54   Value: RT Plan or RT Ion Plan or Radiation Set to be verified
(0008,3010) Irradiation Event UID                               VR: UI  Length: 56   Value: 
(0010,0010) Patient's Name                                      VR: PN  Length: 14   Value: 
(0010,0020) Patient ID                                          VR: LO  Length: 8    Value: XXXXX
(0010,0030) Patient's Birth Date                                VR: DA  Length: 8    Value: 
(0010,0032) Patient's Birth Time                                VR: TM  Length: 6    Value: 
(0010,0040) Patient's Sex                                       VR: CS  Length: 2    Value:  
(0018,0022) Scan Options                                        VR: CS  Length: 8    Value: STANDARD
(0018,0050) Slice Thickness                                     VR: DS  Length: 16   Value: 1.99621475530568
(0018,0060) KVP                                                 VR: DS  Length: 4    Value: 100 
(0018,0090) Data Collection Diameter                            VR: DS  Length: 16   Value: 492.365501391455
(0018,1000) Device Serial Number                                VR: LO  Length: 4    Value: 
(0018,1020) Software Version(s)                                 VR: LO  Length: 8    Value: 
(0018,1100) Reconstruction Diameter                             VR: DS  Length: 6    Value: 281.6 
(0018,1110) Distance Source to Detector                         VR: DS  Length: 4    Value: 1540
(0018,1111) Distance Source to Patient                          VR: DS  Length: 4    Value: 1000
(0018,1120) Gantry/Detector Tilt                                VR: DS  Length: 2    Value: 0 
(0018,1130) Table Height                                        VR: DS  Length: 6    Value: 166.51
(0018,1140) Rotation Direction                                  VR: CS  Length: 2    Value: CC
(0018,1150) Exposure Time                                       VR: IS  Length: 4    Value: 4630
(0018,1151) X-Ray Tube Current                                  VR: IS  Length: 2    Value: 30
(0018,1152) Exposure                                            VR: IS  Length: 4    Value: 138 
(0018,1160) Filter Type                                         VR: SH  Length: 12   Value: Tit V2,HF V2
(0018,1190) Focal Spot(s)                                       VR: DS  Length: 2    Value: 1 
(0018,1210) Convolution Kernel                                  VR: SH  Length: 4    Value: None
(0018,5100) Patient Position                                    VR: CS  Length: 4    Value: HFS 
(0018,9345) CTDIvol                                             VR: FD  Length: 8    Value: 3.666960 
(0018,9346) CTDI Phantom Type Code Sequence                     VR: SQ  Length: 84   
    (FFFE,E000) 
        (0008,0100) Code Value                                          VR: SH  Length: 6    Value: 113690
        (0008,0102) Coding Scheme Designator                            VR: SH  Length: 4    Value: DCM 
        (0008,0103) Coding Scheme Version                               VR: SH  Length: 8    Value: 20061023
        (0008,0104) Code Meaning                                        VR: LO  Length: 26   Value: IEC Head Dosimetry Phantom
(0020,000D) Study Instance UID                                  VR: UI  Length: 52   Value: 1.2.840.113619.2.278.3.346865037.388.15390421XX.XXX 
(0020,000E) Series Instance UID                                 VR: UI  Length: 58   Value: 1.2.246.352.62.2.4715824891563742196.178434434465388XXXXX
(0020,0010) Study ID                                            VR: SH  Length: 6    Value: XXXXX  
(0020,0011) Series Number                                       VR: IS  Length: 2    Value: 2 
(0020,0012) Acquisition Number                                  VR: IS  Length: 2    Value: 1 
(0020,0013) Image Number                                        VR: IS  Length: 2    Value: 19
(0020,0032) Image Position (Patient)                            VR: DS  Length: 34   Value: -140.525\-140.525\-61.882657414476
(0020,0037) Image Orientation (Patient)                         VR: DS  Length: 12   Value: 1\0\0\0\1\0 
(0020,0052) Frame of Reference UID                              VR: UI  Length: 58   Value: 
(0020,1040) Position Reference Indicator                        VR: LO  Length: 0    
(0020,4000) Image Comments                                      VR: LT  Length: 72   Value: Reconstruction Mode THREE_D
Filter STANDARD
Ring Suppression MEDIUM

(0028,0002) Samples per Pixel                                   VR: US  Length: 2    Value: 1 
(0028,0004) Photometric Interpretation                          VR: CS  Length: 12   Value: MONOCHROME2 
(0028,0010) Rows                                                VR: US  Length: 2    Value: 512 
(0028,0011) Columns                                             VR: US  Length: 2    Value: 512 
(0028,0030) Pixel Spacing                                       VR: DS  Length: 10   Value: 0.55\0.55 
(0028,0100) Bits Allocated                                      VR: US  Length: 2    Value: 16 
(0028,0101) Bits Stored                                         VR: US  Length: 2    Value: 16 
(0028,0102) High Bit                                            VR: US  Length: 2    Value: 15 
(0028,0103) Pixel Representation                                VR: US  Length: 2    Value: 0 
(0028,1050) Window Center                                       VR: DS  Length: 4    Value: -50 
(0028,1051) Window Width                                        VR: DS  Length: 4    Value: 670 
(0028,1052) Rescale Intercept                                   VR: DS  Length: 6    Value: -1000 
(0028,1053) Rescale Slope                                       VR: DS  Length: 2    Value: 1 
(0028,1054) Rescale Type                                        VR: LO  Length: 2    Value: HU
(300A,0122) Patient Support Angle                               VR: DS  Length: 2    Value: 0 
(300A,0129) Table Top Longitudinal Position                     VR: DS  Length: 16   Value: 1518.00350447863
(300A,012A) Table Top Lateral Position                          VR: DS  Length: 16   Value: 9.67474747474753
(3253,0010)                                                     VR: LO  Length: 34   Value: Varian Medical Systems VISION 3253
(3253,1000)                                                     VR: ST  Length: 484  Value: (Long Size Data)
(3253,1001)                                                     VR: IS  Length: 2    Value: 0 
(3253,1002)                                                     VR: CS  Length: 16   Value: ImageProcessing
```

Following is the dump for CT header:

```
(0002,0000) Group Length                                        VR: UL  Length: 4    Value: 184 
(0002,0001) File Meta Information Version                       VR: OB  Length: 2    Value: 0
(0002,0002) Media Storage SOP Class UID                         VR: UI  Length: 26   Value: 
(0002,0003) Media Storage SOP Instance UID                      VR: UI  Length: 54   Value: 
(0002,0010) Transfer Syntax UID                                 VR: UI  Length: 18   Value: 
(0002,0012) Implementation Class UID                            VR: UI  Length: 24   Value: 
(0002,0013) Implementation Version Name                         VR: SH  Length: 8    Value: DCIE 2.2
(0008,0005) Specific Character Set                              VR: CS  Length: 10   Value: ISO_IR 192
(0008,0008) Image Type                                          VR: CS  Length: 22   Value: ORIGINAL\PRIMARY\AXIAL
(0008,0012) Instance Creation Date                              VR: DA  Length: 8    Value: 20181115
(0008,0013) Instance Creation Time                              VR: TM  Length: 6    Value: 151330
(0008,0016) SOP Class UID                                       VR: UI  Length: 26   Value: 
(0008,0018) SOP Instance UID                                    VR: UI  Length: 54   Value: 1.2.840.113619.2.278.3.346865037.388.1539042181.XXX.XX
(0008,0020) Study Date                                          VR: DA  Length: 8    Value: 20181009
(0008,0021) Series Date                                         VR: DA  Length: 8    Value: 20181009
(0008,0022) Acquisition Date                                    VR: DA  Length: 8    Value: 20181009
(0008,0023) Image Date                                          VR: DA  Length: 8    Value: 20181009
(0008,0030) Study Time                                          VR: TM  Length: 6    Value: 111141
(0008,0031) Series Time                                         VR: TM  Length: 6    Value: 111308
(0008,0032) Acquisition Time                                    VR: TM  Length: 10   Value: 111515.407
(0008,0033) Image Time                                          VR: TM  Length: 6    Value: 111520
(0008,0050) Accession Number                                    VR: SH  Length: 0    
(0008,0060) Modality                                            VR: CS  Length: 2    Value: CT
(0008,0070) Manufacturer                                        VR: LO  Length: 18   Value: GE MEDICAL SYSTEMS
(0008,0080) Institution Name                                    VR: LO  Length: 26   Value: 
(0008,0090) Referring Physician's Name                          VR: PN  Length: 8    Value:  
(0008,1010) Station Name                                        VR: SH  Length: 4    Value: rtct
(0008,1030) Study Description                                   VR: LO  Length: 2    Value: HN
(0008,103E) Series Description                                  VR: LO  Length: 12   Value: CHEST 2.5 MM
(0008,1048) Physician(s) of Record                              VR: PN  Length: 14   Value:  
(0008,1070) Operators' Name                                     VR: PN  Length: 14   Value: 
(0008,1090) Manufacturer's Model Name                           VR: LO  Length: 18   Value: Discovery CT590 RT
(0008,1140) Referenced Image Sequence                           VR: SQ  Length: 104  
    (FFFE,E000) 
        (0008,1150) Referenced SOP Class UID                            VR: UI  Length: 26   Value: 
        (0008,1155) Referenced SOP Instance UID                         VR: UI  Length: 54   Value: 
(0008,3010) Irradiation Event UID                               VR: UI  Length: 52   Value: 
(0010,0010) Patient's Name                                      VR: PN  Length: 14   Value: 
(0010,0020) Patient ID                                          VR: LO  Length: 8    Value: XXXXX
(0010,0030) Patient's Birth Date                                VR: DA  Length: 8    Value: 
(0010,0032) Patient's Birth Time                                VR: TM  Length: 6    Value: 
(0010,0040) Patient's Sex                                       VR: CS  Length: 2    Value:  
(0018,0022) Scan Options                                        VR: CS  Length: 12   Value: HELICAL MODE
(0018,0050) Slice Thickness                                     VR: DS  Length: 4    Value: 2.5 
(0018,0060) KVP                                                 VR: DS  Length: 4    Value: 120 
(0018,0090) Data Collection Diameter                            VR: DS  Length: 4    Value: 500 
(0018,1000) Device Serial Number                                VR: LO  Length: 2    Value: * 
(0018,1020) Software Version(s)                                 VR: LO  Length: 10   Value: rt_bjcl.35
(0018,1100) Reconstruction Diameter                             VR: DS  Length: 4    Value: 650 
(0018,1110) Distance Source to Detector                         VR: DS  Length: 8    Value: 1062.55 
(0018,1111) Distance Source to Patient                          VR: DS  Length: 8    Value: 605.945 
(0018,1120) Gantry/Detector Tilt                                VR: DS  Length: 2    Value: 0 
(0018,1130) Table Height                                        VR: DS  Length: 4    Value: 174 
(0018,1140) Rotation Direction                                  VR: CS  Length: 2    Value: CW
(0018,1150) Exposure Time                                       VR: IS  Length: 4    Value: 856 
(0018,1151) X-Ray Tube Current                                  VR: IS  Length: 2    Value: 99
(0018,1152) Exposure                                            VR: IS  Length: 2    Value: 13
(0018,1160) Filter Type                                         VR: SH  Length: 12   Value: BODY FILTER 
(0018,1170) Generator Power                                     VR: IS  Length: 6    Value: 84000 
(0018,1190) Focal Spot(s)                                       VR: DS  Length: 4    Value: 1.2 
(0018,1210) Convolution Kernel                                  VR: SH  Length: 8    Value: STANDARD
(0018,5100) Patient Position                                    VR: CS  Length: 4    Value: HFS 
(0020,000D) Study Instance UID                                  VR: UI  Length: 52   Value: 1.2.840.113619.2.278.3.346865037.388.15390421XX.XXX
(0020,000E) Series Instance UID                                 VR: UI  Length: 52   Value: 1.2.840.113619.2.278.3.346865037.388.15390421XX.XXX
(0020,0010) Study ID                                            VR: SH  Length: 6    Value:  XXXXX
(0020,0011) Series Number                                       VR: IS  Length: 2    Value: 2 
(0020,0012) Acquisition Number                                  VR: IS  Length: 2    Value: 1 
(0020,0013) Image Number                                        VR: IS  Length: 2    Value: 19
(0020,0032) Image Position (Patient)                            VR: DS  Length: 16   Value: -325\-325\157.5 
(0020,0037) Image Orientation (Patient)                         VR: DS  Length: 12   Value: 1\0\0\0\1\0 
(0020,0052) Frame of Reference UID                              VR: UI  Length: 60   Value: 
(0020,1040) Position Reference Indicator                        VR: LO  Length: 0    
(0020,1041) Slice Location                                      VR: DS  Length: 6    Value: 157.5 
(0028,0002) Samples per Pixel                                   VR: US  Length: 2    Value: 1 
(0028,0004) Photometric Interpretation                          VR: CS  Length: 12   Value: MONOCHROME2 
(0028,0010) Rows                                                VR: US  Length: 2    Value: 512 
(0028,0011) Columns                                             VR: US  Length: 2    Value: 512 
(0028,0030) Pixel Spacing                                       VR: DS  Length: 18   Value: 1.269531\1.269531 
(0028,0100) Bits Allocated                                      VR: US  Length: 2    Value: 16 
(0028,0101) Bits Stored                                         VR: US  Length: 2    Value: 16 
(0028,0102) High Bit                                            VR: US  Length: 2    Value: 15 
(0028,0103) Pixel Representation                                VR: US  Length: 2    Value: 1 
(0028,1050) Window Center                                       VR: DS  Length: 2    Value: 40
(0028,1051) Window Width                                        VR: DS  Length: 4    Value: 400 
(0028,1052) Rescale Intercept                                   VR: DS  Length: 6    Value: -1000 
(0028,1053) Rescale Slope                                       VR: DS  Length: 2    Value: 1 
(0028,1054) Rescale Type                                        VR: LO  Length: 2    Value: HU
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One obvious way to achieve this is to filter (while C-FIND) on tag that differentiates the instances. This is what you are trying to achieve. Problem is that, commonly used filters do not include such tag.
As you are working on Series level, there is no such a tag in C-FIND response as well. I am not sure if such a tag is available in Image level C-FIND response; but even if it is, it is not reliable way as many PACS implementations may not return it.
So this is not possible/reliable through C-FIND.

You have to go one step ahead.
You should retrieve the instances (C-MOVE/C-GET) and filter those on **your C-STORE SCP**.
In that case also, you need to find the tag that differentiates the instances. In your particular case `(0008,0070) Manufacturer` and/or `(0008,1090) Manufacturer's Model Name` can be considered.

Of-course, this is not generalized or standard solution.